# Firestore error after updating to the latest dependecy

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

> Duplicate zip entry [com/google/e/a/a.class == guava-20.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Ascii.class]

How can I fix this? I didn't see any solution here at the changelog : **https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android**

The error occur after changing it from v15.0.0 to the latest version of firebase.

Here's my build.gradle app level.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0 rc1'
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev63-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.32.0'
    implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

While here is my build.gradle in root

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` with question .

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Sufz0UipCXk